# Capybara::ElementNotFound Unable to find Field "Title"

Tags: capybara, ruby-on-rails-5

I can’t figure out what is wrong here. I've scoured the interwebs for hours and only found people with similar issues and I've tried their solutions, but I'm still getting this error. I’m running a test and it’s telling me that it can’t find the element title, but I’m looking at it in my code and I’m seeing it on local host as well. When I view it in inspector it has the field name as Title.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

My _form.html.erb which I'm rendering on the new.html.erb

`<div class='form-group'>
    <div class='control-label col-md-1'>
      <%= f.label :title %>
    </div>
  <div class='col-md-11'>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Title of movie', autofocus: true %>
    </div>`

My controller

`def create
    @movie = current_admin.movies.build(movie_params)
    if @movie.save
      flash[:success] = "Movie has been created"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Movie has not been created"
      render :new
    end
  end`

My feature spec

`fill_in "Title", with: "Movie title"
    fill_in "Synopsis", with: "Lorem Ipsum"
    fill_in "Year released", with: "Date"
    click_button "Add Movie”`

My error

`Capybara::ElementNotFound 
Unable to find field “Title”`

Here is the [GitHub](https://github.com/kylestengline/moviesmoviesmovies/tree/development) if you deem it necessary to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at `page.html` before the fill_in call you can see that your user is not logged in.  This is because you're calling `login_as(@kyle)` which defaults to a scope of :user, but you're attempting to login an Admin.  You want  `login_as(@kyle, scope: :admin)`

Comment: YES!! Thank you so much, Tom! I wasn't aware of the scope thing, being new to RSpec.

Comment: @kyle Scope is a feature of devise.  You should probably read up on it in the devise docs since you've created at least 2 scopes in your app and if you don't understand it you can end up with all sorts of weird issues